# How to log in and than submit a form using java?

Tags: java, cookies

I need to create a java program which should go to a website's login page, log in, than go to an another page of the site and submit a form. I know how to submit a form, but my problem is with the login part. This script should work with multiple sites, some are using cookies and some sessions. Is there any way to solve my problem ?

I can't show you any code because I don't know where to begin, first I should submit the login form and then separately go to the submission page ? I don't know please help me, or please tell me how could I solve this problem: I want to submit a form on various sites automatically, only I will be using this script. Until now I'we created a script in JavaScript  and I'we opend the sites in iframes and I'we discovered that in Google chrome I can control external iframes, too, and I`we used JavaScript to fill the forms automatically, but my problem is that I need to submit files, images too, and I can't do this using only JavaScript. If it's not possible to do this using java please help me to find an another solution, I need to make it fully automated.

Comment: [Submit HTML form using Java](http://kspace.in/blog/2008/05/30/submit-html-form-using-java/).Your question should show some research effort, that link was the 3rd result in a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=submit+a+form+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: I`we searched it an I`we created a script that can submit a simple form before asking here, but I could not make it to log in and submit on separate page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) for logging in to websites using Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) framework and APIs. It's a test automation tool but there's no reason why you couldn't use it for doing programmatic logins to websites. It has client libraries for many languages including Java.

Using selenium RC you can write Java could thatcan load, navigate and fill in forms programmatically. You are able to target the form input fields using field names or classes and the Java API allows you to load multipart data into a form.

Selenium comes in two flavours, the older [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html) version and the newer [WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) version. Both are capable of doing what you want, however they have slightly different ways of doing it. The documentation provides some good examples to get you started.